# Determine whether a TreeViewItem is visible in a virtualized TreeView

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, treeview

I have a customized virtualized treeview that goes funny whenever the user tries to use keyboard navigation (up/down) from a selected TreeViewItem that's not in view (and hence not visually loaded into the virtualized tree).

The solution I'm attempting to implement involves disabling keyboard navigation when the starting node is not yet in view/loaded in the tree.

I can get the starting TreeViewItem/node, however, I don't know how to determine whether it's in view (the IsLoaded prop doesn't help). Does anyone know how I could go about this?

```
        protected override void OnPreviewKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Key == Key.Down)
            {

                var startingItem = (TreeViewItem)e.OriginalSource; // starting treenode

                // how do I check if it's in view/loaded in my virtualized tree?
             }
         }
```

Comment: Describe that "funny". You are asking to solve problem of your attemplted solution to another problem. Which is ... ? Adding [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) will not hurt (and while preparing it you may even solve your problem.. sometimes happens).

Comment: I guess direct answer would be [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21081402/1997232): handle scrolling or use one of virtualizing methods, e.g. [this one](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.virtualizingstackpanel.oncleanupvirtualizeditem(v=vs.110).aspx) .

Comment: @Sinatr I didn't want to get too bogged down in the details, because I have a lot of custom behavior built into this treeview and while it would be great to get the keyboard navigation working normally, I'm not sure that endeavor is right for Stack. But that said, the problems are: 1. if you have an off-screen selected node and try to navigate towards the viewed region (not away), it most often freezes up/doesn't affect the navigation; 2. if you have an off-screen selectednode with ~10,000 or more peers, keyboard nav will freeze the app up (bc it appears to be trying to load all TreeViewItems.